# Batch file to move a folder into another

Tags: batch-file, cmd, move

my question is how can I take a folder containing a word in its title and move it into a certain folder?

What I am trying to do is take any folder containing the name "Oscar" and move it into my "Movies" folder.

I honestly don't know much about this type of coding, and did some research and this is the best I could come up with.

```
move D:\Downloads\"Oscar" D:\Downloads\Movies
```

Now when I change oscar to the full name of the folder, it works, I would like to have it work using only a partial name.

I'm assuming some sort of loop would be used in order to move all of them, I just don't know much of what I am doing here.

Thank you everyone in advance.

Comment: What do you mean by "move **it**?" Do you mean move Oscar's files to your destination, or move the directory "*Oscar*" so that it becomes a subdirectory of the destination specified?

Comment: @Magoo So say I have a folder "Birdman - Oscar Nominated" I want to take that folder or even just the contents of the folder and move it to the folder "Movies". I want the script to see that it contains the string "Oscar" and then take the folder (or just its contents) and move it completely to the "Movies" Folder

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Run this command inside the folder `D:\Downloads` with the cmd prompt:

```
FOR /D %i IN (oscar*) DO move "%i" movies
```

If you are doing this inside of a batch script (instead of in the cmd prompt) replace the `%i` by `%%i`.

Comment: This seems to have worked. Thank you! My only questions are, is it case sensitive and will it work if say the file name is [Oscar]. Will it read it and move it, even if it is in the brackets? Because it didn't seem to move the ones in the brackets. So I just copy and pasted and changed it up to make it move those as well. Thanks again!

Comment: `*oscar*` in place of `oscar*` would move all "oscar"-containing directories; it's not case-sensitive

Comment: Great! I guess Magoo answered your points. Please consider accepting the answer if it works.

Comment: @Magoo you guys are great! My final question, I have a file and it has "oscarnominated" all one word. How can I get it to include that as well? Because at the moment it seems to only move the files that have "oscar" as its own word. Thanks again

Comment: @Márcio Paiva I accepted your answer. Thanks again!

Comment: @Magoo actually. It might not be because it is one word. I think it might be because the file is not inside a folder. I am not sure if that is why. Would that be a possibility?

Comment: @Ddrossi93: The **file** has to be in a directory by definition. The `/d` in the command directs matching `directory names`. If you want `files` then you need `for /R`